# Parsing XML into Google Maps Program

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, parsing

I'm developing a app at the moment wich displayes a Map, your gps postition and a marker on this postition. Next Step is to recieve Data from a XML file. The XML I'm trying to use is http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/hotpepper/gourmet/v1/?key=899d70a29e983f4b&lat=33.58724&lng=130.3986&range=5&order=4

But poorly after launching the app (on a real device, newest version) the app terminates and displays nothing.
LogCat says FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlparser/com.example.xmlparser.MainActivitz}: java.lang.nullPointerException

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.xmlparser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
public String url = "http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/hotpepper/gourmet/v1/?key=899d70a29e983f4b&lat=33.58724&lng=130.3986&range=5&order=4";
public EditText feldname, id;
public HandleXml obj; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    feldname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } 
    else 
    {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }

    float lat1 = (float) (location.getLatitude());      //Getting the position
    float lng1 = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    GoogleMap mMap;
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1))
            .title("Your Position"));


    LatLng bounds = new LatLng(lat1, lng1);


    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bounds);

    mMap.moveCamera(cu); 
}





//Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    float lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());       //Getting the ' ''
    float lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

public void open(View view)
    {
        feldname.setText(url);
        obj = new HandleXml(url);
          obj.fetchXML();
          while(obj.parsingComplete);
          feldname.setText(obj.getFeldName());
          id.setText(obj.getId());
    }
}

**HandleXml.java**

```
package com.example.xmlparser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HandleXml {

    private String feldname = "name";
    private String id = "id";
    private String urlString = null;
       private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
       public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

       public HandleXml(String url)
       {
          this.urlString = url;
       }
       public String getFeldName()
       {
              return feldname;
       }
       public String getId()
       {
           return id;
       }
       public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) 
       {
              int event;
              String text=null;
              try 
              {
                 event = myParser.getEventType();
                 while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
                 {
                    String name=myParser.getName();
                    switch (event)
                    {
                       case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                       break;
                       case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                       text = myParser.getText();
                       break;

                       case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                          if(name.equals("name_kana"))
                          {
                              feldname = text;
                          }
                          else if(name.equals("id"))
                          {     
                              id =text;// myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                          }

                          else
                          {}
                          break;
                          }      
                          event = myParser.next(); 

                      }
                         parsingComplete = false;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }

           }
       public void fetchXML()
       {
              Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
              {
                 @Override
                 public void run() 
                 {
                    try 
                    {
                       URL url = new URL(urlString);
                       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                       url.openConnection();                                        
                          conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                          conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                          conn.setDoInput(true);
                          conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
                    , false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start(); 


           }

        }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xmlparser"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<permission
android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xmlparser.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyC3DipaFNo1EC44rZ8N1AJKVAiUCNOtqZw"/>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I really hope one of you can tell me whats wrong with this code as it was working perfectly fine with only the map on it's own and the parser as an own program.

Comment: Man your code is a complete mess, try doing things step by step ;)

Comment: @Yume117 Did how you recommendet, new code, new problem, maybe you risk another look

Comment: What line give you the null pointer exception ?

Comment: @Yume117 Line 73, it is a problem with the location manager, it worked fine in the beginnign but now it seems like i have to add hard numbers, also trying to change the variables to double or int did not work

Comment: When u say line 73, it doesn't help me since i don't know which line is which ;)

Comment: @Yume117 these 2, sorry
    float lat1 = (float) (location.getLatitude());      
    float lng1 = (float) (location.getLongitude());

Comment: Your logic is not really good. First you test if location is null or not, an then if it's null you only update the textview. In the case it is null the rest of the code ll throw a null pointer it is obvious. I'll post some code i use to get location more safely